# How to handle Multiple Webpack Builds based on differant ES Version?

Tags: javascript, webpack, babeljs, html-webpack-plugin

tl;dr

How to export different versions of my script `main.js` as `main-es-2017.js` and `main-es5.js` and include both these files in my HTML?

The Long version of the question:

when we transpile files into ES5 there is some unnecessary code is added which is not required for the modern browsers hence I wanted to export multiple versions of my script one for the old browsers and one for new browsers.

I understand that we can simply load different files with a simple `nomodule` attribute but how to handle that with the Webpack.

I am using the [HTMLWebpack plugin](https://webpack.js.org/plugins/html-webpack-plugin/) to create HTML and I am using [HTML No Module plugin](https://github.com/swimmadude66/webpack-nomodule-plugin) for adding No Module attribute.

Reference Link: https://philipwalton.com/articles/deploying-es2015-code-in-production-today/

Thanks in advance!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After wracking my brain around the web, I could not find an answer so I had to implement a custom solution that I would not recommend so before going for a custom solution there is a third party addon named "[HTMLWebpackTagsPlugin](https://github.com/jharris4/html-webpack-tags-plugin)" for adding assets to your generated HTML, you can add CSS of JS files to your HTML file after the build is successful.

Although this was not a solution for me since the build was running multiple times which was overriding the generated HTML.

My solution:
I created an addon for the Webpack HTML Plugin which notes down the build file path and then I created a custom script that runs after the build is successful and injects the build scripts into the HTML.

I will try to create an open-source code template that will be easy for everyone to understand.